# Regex to contain A-Z 0-9 and/or spaces, parenthesis or hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get my regex to evaluate to true if it contains A-Z0-9, and also if the A-Z0-9 has spaces in it anywhere, parenthesis anywhere, or hyphens anywhere.

So far I've got this which matches A-Z0-9 () " " and hyphen but I want to make the parenthesis/space/hyphen optional. How can I do this without heaps of if statements?

so far:

```
if(str.matches("^[A-Z0-9 ()-?]+$"){
    return str;
}
```

how can I make those parenthesis/hyphen/space optional? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a pattern which only matches if letters or digits definitely are present in the sequence, but also allows parentheses, spaces and hyphens too?

Comment: Everything in character classes are optional, literally OR'd with each other, but still requiring one of those characters to match. Even if you use `[a-zA-Z0-9 ()-]+` is says nothing about what is required to be there. In this case it could match "((((((((((((("

Comment: Can you please provide examples of what should be valid or invalid? Your Question is ambigious.

Answer (score 0):

If matching `A-Z0-9` is needed with rest as optional then in Java you just need:

```
if (str.matches("(?=.*?[A-Z0-9])[A-Z0-9 ()-]+") {
    return str;
}
```

- `(?=.*?[A-Z0-9])` is a lookahead to ensure there is at least one character in `[A-Z0-9]` class.
- Removed `?` as `?` is taken literally in character class.
- Space, parentheses and hyphen will be optional.
- `matches` doesn't need anchors as it attempts to match full input with the regex given.

Comment: Your pattern will also match `(-)` - which is not a composition of `A-Z0-9` with optional `-( )`

Comment: Well if `A-Z0-9` is mandatory then yes it will happen, I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, `A-Z0-9` is mandatory with optional `( )-` - right?

Then you need to ensure that you match at least one time `A-Z0-9`:

```
^[A-Z0-9 ()-]*[A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9 ()-]*$
```

This will match

```
A
AB9D
A(9-
-BC)
-8-D
```

but not

```
(-
---
)))
-
```

Debuggex:

```
^[A-Z0-9 ()-]*[A-Z0-9]+[A-Z0-9 ()-]*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YOeTKfuWPrYIiEVl)